# There is a way to set up Synapse Administrators with a BICEP module?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-bicep

I would like to set Synapse access control with a bicep module but I can't find a proper resource to use.

Please, can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

UPDATE:
basend on evgeny answer, I tryed in this way but it seems not working:

```
resource syRBAC1 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/administrators@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'activeDirectory'
  parent: synapse_workspace
  properties: {
    administratorType: 'Synapse SQL Administrator'
    login: 'mylogin@mycompany.com'
    sid: ELSCId
    tenantId: TenantId
  }
}
```

It does not produce any error but it does not change any change into the access control list.

Probably it sets only this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I came across the same problem and bicep does not offer a way to assign the role (yet) I added an AzureCLI task to my pipeline and grant the role via `az synapse role assignment create` after the deployment.

Output defined in the bicep file to pass the name of the newly created synapse workspace along to the AzureCLI task:

```
output synapse_workspace_name string = synapse_workspace.name
```

Tasks in the deployment pipeline's yml file :

```
// deployment task via "main.bicep" file
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    connectedServiceName: $(ServiceConnectionName)
    location: $(DeploymentDefaultLocation)
    resourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroupName)
    csmFile: main.bicep
    overrideParameters: >
        -aad_admin_developer_group_object_id $(AadAdminDeveloperGroupObjectId)
    deploymentOutputs: deployment_output  

// Grant "Synapse Administrator"
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Assign role "Synapse Administrator" on the newly created Synapse workspace to the developer AAD-Group'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my_subscription'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az synapse role assignment create --workspace-name $(deployment_output.synapse_workspace_name.value) --role "Synapse Administrator" --assignee $(AadAdminDeveloperGroupObjectId)'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update

Based on the discussion on the [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/25790), here's a functioning workaround to set up a workspace with an administrator using only Bicep:

```
// Create the Synapse workspace
resource synapse 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'xxxx'
  location: location
  ...
}

// Create a managed identity used for the role assignment during the deployment
resource userAssignedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  name: 'xxxx'
  location: location
}

// Assign the Azure RBAC "Owner" role on the Synapse workspace to the managed identity just created
var roleDefinitionId = subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635') // Owner
resource identityRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(subscription().subscriptionId, userAssignedIdentity.properties.principalId, roleDefinitionId)
  scope: synapse
  properties: {
    principalId: userAssignedIdentity.properties.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionId
  }
}

// Assign the Synapse RBAC role "Synapse Adminitrator" to a given principalId
resource synapseRoleAssignRBAC 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'synapseRoleAssignAZ-${uniqueString(synapse.name, principalId)}'
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${userAssignedIdentity.properties.principalId}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    forceUpdateTag: '1'
    azCliVersion: '2.42.0'
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
    environmentVariables: [
      {
        name: 'subscription'
        value: subscription().subscriptionId
      }
      {
        name: 'workspace'
        value: synapse.name
      }
      {
        name: 'role'
        value: '6e4bf58a-b8e1-4cc3-bbf9-d73143322b78'
      }
      {
        name: 'assignee'
        value: principalId
      }
    ]
    scriptContent: '''
      # az synapse role assignment is not idempotent and the output must therefore be verified
      RESULT=$(az synapse role assignment create --workspace-name "$workspace" --role "$role" --assignee "$assignee" 2>&1)
      EXIT_CODE=$?

      if  [ "$EXIT_CODE" != 0 ]; then
          # If the error is of type "RoleAssignmentAlreadyExists", then it's fine
          if [[ "$RESULT" == *"RoleAssignmentAlreadyExists"* ]]; then
              echo "The Synapse role assignment already existed"
          else
              # If this was a different error, then print it to stderr and exit with the same error code
              echo $RESULT 1>&2
              exit $EXIT_CODE
          fi
      fi
      echo $RESULT
    '''
  }
}
```

## Original message

### Synapse Azure Active Directory admin

I've been spending some time trying to use `Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/administrators` and got it to work... but unfortunately that didn't really help!

For reference, here's how I managed to use it:

```
resource synapseADAdmin 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/administrators@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'activeDirectory' // Only valid value
  parent: synapse_workspace
  properties: {
    administratorType: 'activeDirectory' // Also seems to be the only valid value
    login: 'mylogin@mycompany.com' // Optional
    sid: principalId
    tenantId: TenantId
  }
}
```

It seems that `sid` can be the principal ID of any Azure AD object (tried with user, group and managed identity).

You were right that it does correspond to the "Azure Active Directory" tab of the workspace settings:
[Azure AD admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0zr8.png)

### Using a Bicep deployment script to assign Synapse roles

As an alternative to Cribber's answer, you can also use Azure CLI as a deployment script in your Bicep module:

```
resource synapseRoleAssign 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' =  {
  name: 'synapseRoleAssign-${uniqueString(role, principalId)}'
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${userAssignedIdentityId}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    forceUpdateTag: '1'
    azCliVersion: '2.42.0'
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
    environmentVariables: [
      {
        name: 'subscription'
        value: subscription().subscriptionId
      }
      {
        name: 'workspace'
        value: synapse.name
      }
      {
        name: 'role'
        value: role
      }
      {
        name: 'assignee'
        value: principalId
      }
    ]
    scriptContent: '''
      az account set --subscription "$subscription"
      az synapse role assignment create --workspace-name "$workspace" --role "$role" --assignee "$assignee"
    '''
  }
}
```

The catch is that the service principal used must have the proper Synapse RBAC permission, so you still have to manually grant it the Synapse Administrator role from within the workspace.

### How to provision a service principal for the deployment script?

I've explored several options to avoid the manual step of assigning an user assigned identity the "Synapse Administrator" role:

- Setting the user assigned identity as Synapse workspace's Azure AD admin (using the resource `Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/administrators` above). That didn't help at all. I have no clue on the role of the workspace AD administrator :(
- Using the workspace's managed identity to run the deployment script doesn't work because only user assigned identities, not system managed identities can be used for deployment scripts.
- Setting the user assigned identity as the Synapse workspace's initial admin:

  ```
   cspWorkspaceAdminProperties: {
     initialWorkspaceAdminObjectId: principalId
   }
  ```

  This seems to change the "SQL Active Directory admin", but the user assigned identity is still not added as "Synapse Administrator" within the workspace (and, weirdly, my user account still is).
- Adding the user assigned identity to the workspace's managed identities doesn't give it the "Synapse Administrator" role either.

... I reached the conclusion that there is a bug with both the PoweShell Azure Az module and az cli as it should be possible to assign a Synapse Administrator when you're an owner of the Synapse workspace in Azure RBAC. I have raised an [issue for this bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/25790).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the templates for Synapse workspace are not mature yet and the documentation is poorly written. This is how I managed to use the `'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/administrators@2021-06-01'` template:

Create a managed identity for Synapse:

```
resource synapseMi 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2022-01-31-preview' = {
  name: replace(resourceGroup().name, 'rg', 'mi')
  location: location
  tags: tags
}
```

Assign the managed identity as AAD admin for synapse workspace:

```
@description('Assign synapse-mi as admin of synapse workspace')
resource synapseMiAdminAssignment 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/administrators@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'activeDirectory'
  parent: synapseWorkspace
  properties: {
    administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
    sid: synapseMi.properties.principalId
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
  }
}
```

If you go to Azure portal -> your Synapse Workspace -> Azure Active Directory you can see the admin as synapse mi you just set.

I still need to test whether it reflects in the permissions.

LE: This change is only reflected in the azure portal resource and NOT in the Synapse RBAC, so it doesn't work as intended.

For now, the only workaround, as @Cribber suggested is to grant the permissions in a separate Pipeline task via az cli or AzPs. I have also opened a feature request on github for visibility purposes -> https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/issues/1972

Answer (score -2):

This is done using `Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/administrators` and deployed as a child resource (also to a resource group scope).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.synapse/workspaces/administrators?tabs=bicep

Comment: What is the administratorType? Can I choose for example 'Synapse SQL Administrator' or 'Synapse Contributor'? if yes, how? by role name?

Comment: Same question. I can't actually figure out how to use that template. I'm trying to add a Security Group as the administrator, so what do I put for `administratorType` and `login`?

Comment: third to come here, and you lot didn't think of adding whatever you found.... reminds me of an XKCD comic. @MBuschi

Comment: still looking for a solution. domanually for now